# Can I have Magic Vestment spell on armor and shield simultaneously?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Magic Vestment spell says you can imbue a suit of armor OR a shield with an enhancement bonus. So, you must decide which armor or which shield you imbue with the bonus. Lets say I decide my nom magic full plate armor. By casting second magic vestment spell I decide to imbue my new masterwork non magical heavy steel shield. Will the spells operate both?

Comment: Any reason you think it would not? The only possible answer I can see is just a flat "yes", but that's not a very useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magic Vestment:

> You imbue a suit of armor or a shield with an enhancement bonus of +1

Casting it on a suit of full plate and a shield gives you a +1 Full Plate and a +1 shield.

Enhancement bonuses on armour gives it an increase to Armour Bonus, and shields to Deflection, which stack.

This would not stack if the spell gave a specific bonus, such as giving a Deflection or Armour bonus to an item, thus giving you a shield and armour with the same magical bonus.

But as Magic Vestment gives them an Enhancement bonus, the normal rules for enchanted equipment applies, and a cast on each item will stack.

Comment: @CarlosSatyros Please note, while you definitely can benefit from multiple instances of Magic Vestment, the spell gives Enhancement bonuses to both armor and shield AC not Deflection bonus. It may make some difference (if you are concerned about your Touch AC for example).

Comment: RAW: Shield enhancement bonuses stack with armor enhancement bonuses.

Comment: While the end result is correct, this post is very inaccurate. The spell does give a specific bonus, an enhancement bonus, which adds to your shield or armor bonus. A deflection bonus would stack with these effects, as would any other non- armor bonus or shield bonus.

Comment: But deflection/armour don't stack with themselves, which is what I said. If the spell gave deflection to the plate and the shield, it wouldn't stack.